# Query string in Bokeh Python

Tags: python, bokeh

I have developed a Bokeh App. hosted on Windows Server. I need query string passed in browser to manipulate my plots.

```
192.168.190.126/bokehApp?csv=xyz.csv&tsv=abc.tsv
```

I want to know the values after ?.

Answer (score 0):

As of `0.12` this is an [open feature request](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/4828), which will hopefully be implemented soon. The issue does have a prototype implementation, if you are able to run from your own forked or patched version.

Comment: Will embedding the bokeh app with flask solve the problem? because from flask we can get URL using – from flask import request and request has the URL

Comment: That might possibly work, but I have not tried it, so I cannot say for certain. FYI there is now an in-flight PR to add this feature: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/4858 that will be in at least a dev build very soon (might not make it into `0.12.1`)

Answer (score 0):

This feature was added (as mentioned [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/4894)).

To query the "??csv=xyz.csv&tsv=abc.tsv" part of the HTML see the attributes of the request, i.e., in the `on_session_created` function the attributes passed by url are in the `session_context` variable as `session_context.reques.arguments`.

In your case if we have:

```
def on_session_created(session_context):
    ''' If present, this function is called when a session is created. '''
    print "Arguments after '?': {}".format(session_context.request.arguments)
```

After running `bokeh serve bokehApp` and pasting `192.168.190.126/bokehApp?csv=xyz.csv&tsv=abc.tsv` on the browser the output on terminal would be:

```
Arguments after '?': {'csv':'xyz.csv', 'tsv':'abc.tsv'}
```

Note that the `on_session_created function` is on the server_lifecycle.py.